# YouCompleteMe in non-code files yields -- User defined completion (^U^N^P) Pattern not found

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-you-complete-me

I use [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) and it works great (after some setting up woes) for both C/C++ and Python code.  However, it tries to complete things in text files such as ReStructured text, markdown, etc...

The error I keep getting is:

```
-- User defined completion (^U^N^P) Pattern not found
```

How can I stop it form doing so?

I did try this:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp,python let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = "~/.ycm_extra_conf.py"
autocmd FileType c,cpp,python let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files = 1
autocmd FileType c,cpp,python let g:ycm_complete_in_comments = 0
autocmd FileType c,cpp,python let g:ycm_complete_in_strings = 0
autocmd FileType c,cpp,python let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
autocmd FileType c,cpp,python let g:syntastic_error_symbol = '✗'
autocmd FileType c,cpp,python let g:syntastic_warning_symbol = '⚠'
autocmd FileType c,cpp,python let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 0
```

But the error still persists.  I even tried adding a `g:ycm_filetype_specific_completion_to_disable` command like so:

```
let g:ycm_filetype_specific_completion_to_disable = {
      \ 'rst': 1
      \}
```

But the error still persists.

Comment: Is a solution to enable it for only certain files ok? Or do you also want it for example disabled in C comments but enabled in code?

Comment: @Shahbaz: Enabling it only for certain files types is a solution I'd accept. However, your second sounds awesome if it were possible! ^_~

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `g:ycm_filetype_whitelist` was the one I needed!

```
let g:ycm_filetype_whitelist = { 'cpp': 1, 'c': 1, 'python':1 }
```

Finally, to get ride of this message altogether, the [answer is in the FAQ](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#i-get-annoying-messages-in-vims-status-area-when-i-type). Basically, update to Vim 7.4.314 or later and it shall go away.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a generic answer, since I don't know `YouCompleteMe`. You mentioned in the comments that you would be ok with enabling this plugin on a per-file basis, so here is the solution:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp <command>
```

The command above executes `command` whenever a `c` or `cpp` filetype is detected. If you have filetype detection enabled on startup, this means the command would execute when you open a `c` or `cpp` file. Furthermore, remember that the effect may be on all opened splits (see `set` vs `setlocal`). `:h autocmd` and `:h filetypes` have additional information.

That said, you need to find the command that enables/disables `YouCompleteMe` and stick it in an autocommand.

Comment: Yup, I did try that but no joy. I get the same error.